# How to make your own font?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, fonts, editing

I've always wanted to make my own font, is there a font creating application which will have the following features?:

- Ability to draw fonts with different tools (similar collection of tools to GIMP, the ability to change the thickness of lines, and layers)
- Ability to import and edit already existing fonts in the ttf, eol, and svg formats
- Ability to export fonts in the ttf, eol, and svg format
- Ability to create name, description, copyright notice, and specify if it is a normal, **bold**, or *italic*, or ***bold and italic***

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Birdfont` is just the application for you then! **Install** it with:

```
sudo apt-get install birdfont
```

You can do all of what you have requested and more with it!

**Description:**

```
Font editor that lets you create outline vector graphics and export fonts
Birdfont is a free, open source font editor that lets you create outline
vector graphics and export ttf, eot & svg fonts.
```

**Screenshots (but please don't judge the program by my bad drawing of the letter A where I should have drawn the letter B ;P):**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: While the installation in **ubuntu 16.04.5** happens without a warning, starting birdfont gives `birdfont: error while loading shared libraries: libxmlbird.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Note: Installation with *apt* and use in **Ubuntu 20.04.1** is no problemo.